# MongoDB in Docker claims user was successfully created, but login still fails

Tags: authentication, docker, mongodb

I am trying to construct a Docker image with MongoDB w/auth and a configured user.  However, even though creating the user works, I can't seem to use that user. The application is a Dropwizard 0.8 project.

I assume that there is some problem with the user creation, but as you can see from the log below, Mongo claims that the user was successfully created.

The command I use to build the image:

```
docker build -t id-srv -f Dockerfile . && docker-compose up --build
```

Here are the logs from the my-mongo build:

```
$ docker build -t my-mongo -f Dockerfile-mongo . --no-cache
Sending build context to Docker daemon 73.08 MB
Step 1 : FROM mongo:3.3
 ---> aa57b208cc5d
Step 2 : RUN su - mongodb -c "mongod" & sleep 5; mongo --eval "db.createUser({user: 'peter', pwd: 'password', roles: [{role:'readWrite',db:'progether-id'}]})" a
dmin
 ---> Running in d75db07d9922
2016-10-03T12:08:27.655+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] MongoDB starting : pid=10 port=27017 dbpath=/data/db 64-bit host=383850eeb47b
2016-10-03T12:08:27.655+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] db version v3.3.15
2016-10-03T12:08:27.655+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] git version: 520f5571d039b57cf9c319b49654909828971073
2016-10-03T12:08:27.655+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] OpenSSL version: OpenSSL 1.0.1t  3 May 2016
2016-10-03T12:08:27.656+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] allocator: tcmalloc
2016-10-03T12:08:27.656+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] modules: none
2016-10-03T12:08:27.656+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] build environment:
2016-10-03T12:08:27.656+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     distmod: debian81
2016-10-03T12:08:27.656+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     distarch: x86_64
2016-10-03T12:08:27.656+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     target_arch: x86_64
2016-10-03T12:08:27.656+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] options: {}
2016-10-03T12:08:27.661+0000 I STORAGE  [initandlisten]
2016-10-03T12:08:27.661+0000 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] ** WARNING: Using the XFS filesystem is strongly recommended with the WiredTiger storage engine
2016-10-03T12:08:27.661+0000 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] See http://dochub.mongodb.org/core/prodnotes-filesystem
2016-10-03T12:08:27.661+0000 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] wiredtiger_open config: create,cache_size=256M,session_max=20000,eviction=(threads_max=4),config_base=fa
lse,statistics=(fast),log=(enabled=true,archive=true,path=journal,compressor=snappy),file_manager=(close_idle_time=100000),checkpoint=(wait=60,log_size=2GB),sta
tistics_log=(wait=0),
2016-10-03T12:08:27.696+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]
2016-10-03T12:08:27.696+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] ** NOTE: This is a development version (3.3.15) of MongoDB.
2016-10-03T12:08:27.696+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] **       Not recommended for production.
2016-10-03T12:08:27.696+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]
2016-10-03T12:08:27.697+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] ** WARNING: Access control is not enabled for the database.
2016-10-03T12:08:27.697+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] **          Read and write access to data and configuration is unrestricted.
2016-10-03T12:08:27.697+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]
2016-10-03T12:08:27.697+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]
2016-10-03T12:08:27.697+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] ** WARNING: /sys/kernel/mm/transparent_hugepage/enabled is 'always'.
2016-10-03T12:08:27.697+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] **        We suggest setting it to 'never'
2016-10-03T12:08:27.698+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]
2016-10-03T12:08:27.698+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] ** WARNING: /sys/kernel/mm/transparent_hugepage/defrag is 'always'.
2016-10-03T12:08:27.698+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] **        We suggest setting it to 'never'
2016-10-03T12:08:27.698+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]
2016-10-03T12:08:27.707+0000 I FTDC     [initandlisten] Initializing full-time diagnostic data capture with directory '/data/db/diagnostic.data'
2016-10-03T12:08:27.716+0000 I INDEX    [initandlisten] build index on: admin.system.version properties: { v: 2, key: { version: 1 }, name: "incompatible_with_v
ersion_32", ns: "admin.system.version" }
2016-10-03T12:08:27.716+0000 I INDEX    [initandlisten]          building index using bulk method
2016-10-03T12:08:27.717+0000 I INDEX    [initandlisten] build index done.  scanned 0 total records. 0 secs
2016-10-03T12:08:27.719+0000 I NETWORK  [thread1] waiting for connections on port 27017
MongoDB shell version v3.3.15
connecting to: mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/admin
2016-10-03T12:08:32.766+0000 I NETWORK  [thread1] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:45594 #1 (1 connection now open)
2016-10-03T12:08:32.767+0000 I NETWORK  [conn1] received client metadata from 127.0.0.1:45594 conn1: { application: { name: "MongoDB Shell" }, driver: { name: "
MongoDB Internal Client", version: "3.3.15" }, os: { type: "Linux", name: "PRETTY_NAME="Debian GNU/Linux 8 (jessie)"", architecture: "x86_64", version: "Kernel
4.4.16-boot2docker" } }
MongoDB server version: 3.3.15
Successfully added user: {
        "user" : "peter",
        "roles" : [
                {
                        "role" : "readWrite",
                        "db" : "progether-id"
                }
        ]
}
2016-10-03T12:08:32.792+0000 I -        [conn1] end connection 127.0.0.1:45594 (1 connection now open)
 ---> 7095cab20aa3
Removing intermediate container d75db07d9922
Step 3 : RUN rm /tmp/mongodb-*.sock
 ---> Running in 418278f9b413
 ---> 3f0af9638969
Removing intermediate container 418278f9b413
Step 4 : CMD mongod --auth --smallfiles
 ---> Running in cf50e0920661
 ---> 41b81d0634b3
Removing intermediate container cf50e0920661
Successfully built 41b81d0634b3
SECURITY WARNING: You are building a Docker image from Windows against a non-Windows Docker host. All files and directories added to build context will have '-r
wxr-xr-x' permissions. It is recommended to double check and reset permissions for sensitive files and directories.
```

Here are the logs from docker-compose:

```
$ docker-compose up --build
Starting identityservice_mongo_1
Starting identityservice_identify-service_1
Attaching to identityservice_mongo_1, identityservice_identify-service_1
←[36mmongo_1             |←[0m 2016-10-03T12:03:21.182+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] MongoDB starting : pid=1 port=27017 dbpath=/data/db 64-bit host=e74532b51
0ca
←[36mmongo_1             |←[0m 2016-10-03T12:03:21.183+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] db version v3.3.15
←[36mmongo_1             |←[0m 2016-10-03T12:03:21.183+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] git version: 520f5571d039b57cf9c319b49654909828971073
←[36mmongo_1             |←[0m 2016-10-03T12:03:21.183+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] OpenSSL version: OpenSSL 1.0.1t  3 May 2016
←[36mmongo_1             |←[0m 2016-10-03T12:03:21.183+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] allocator: tcmalloc
←[36mmongo_1             |←[0m 2016-10-03T12:03:21.183+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] modules: none
←[36mmongo_1             |←[0m 2016-10-03T12:03:21.184+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] build environment:
←[36mmongo_1             |←[0m 2016-10-03T12:03:21.184+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     distmod: debian81
←[36mmongo_1             |←[0m 2016-10-03T12:03:21.184+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     distarch: x86_64
←[36mmongo_1             |←[0m 2016-10-03T12:03:21.184+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     target_arch: x86_64
←[36mmongo_1             |←[0m 2016-10-03T12:03:21.184+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] options: { security: { authorization: "enabled" }, storage: { mmapv1: { s
mallFiles: true } } }
←[36mmongo_1             |←[0m 2016-10-03T12:03:21.188+0000 I -        [initandlisten] Detected data files in /data/db created by the 'mmapv1' storage engine, s
o setting the active storage engine to 'mmapv1'.
←[36mmongo_1             |←[0m 2016-10-03T12:03:21.192+0000 I JOURNAL  [initandlisten] journal dir=/data/db/journal
←[36mmongo_1             |←[0m 2016-10-03T12:03:21.193+0000 I JOURNAL  [initandlisten] recover : no journal files present, no recovery needed
←[36mmongo_1             |←[0m 2016-10-03T12:03:21.231+0000 I JOURNAL  [durability] Durability thread started
←[36mmongo_1             |←[0m 2016-10-03T12:03:21.231+0000 I JOURNAL  [journal writer] Journal writer thread started
←[36mmongo_1             |←[0m 2016-10-03T12:03:21.232+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]
←[36mmongo_1             |←[0m 2016-10-03T12:03:21.232+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] ** NOTE: This is a development version (3.3.15) of MongoDB.
←[36mmongo_1             |←[0m 2016-10-03T12:03:21.232+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] **       Not recommended for production.
←[36mmongo_1             |←[0m 2016-10-03T12:03:21.232+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]
←[36mmongo_1             |←[0m 2016-10-03T12:03:21.233+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]
←[36mmongo_1             |←[0m 2016-10-03T12:03:21.233+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] ** WARNING: /sys/kernel/mm/transparent_hugepage/enabled is 'always'.
←[36mmongo_1             |←[0m 2016-10-03T12:03:21.233+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] **        We suggest setting it to 'never'
←[36mmongo_1             |←[0m 2016-10-03T12:03:21.233+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]
←[36mmongo_1             |←[0m 2016-10-03T12:03:21.233+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] ** WARNING: /sys/kernel/mm/transparent_hugepage/defrag is 'always'.
←[36mmongo_1             |←[0m 2016-10-03T12:03:21.233+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] **        We suggest setting it to 'never'
←[36mmongo_1             |←[0m 2016-10-03T12:03:21.233+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]
←[36mmongo_1             |←[0m 2016-10-03T12:03:21.237+0000 I FTDC     [initandlisten] Initializing full-time diagnostic data capture with directory '/data/db/d
iagnostic.data'
←[36mmongo_1             |←[0m 2016-10-03T12:03:21.238+0000 I NETWORK  [thread1] waiting for connections on port 27017
←[33midentify-service_1  |←[0m INFO  [2016-10-03 12:03:23,472] org.eclipse.jetty.util.log: Logging initialized @2104ms
←[33midentify-service_1  |←[0m DEBUG [2016-10-03 12:03:23,564] com.progether.services.id.IdService: initializing application
←[33midentify-service_1  |←[0m DEBUG [2016-10-03 12:03:23,566] com.progether.services.id.IdService: initializing application/morphia
←[33midentify-service_1  |←[0m INFO  [2016-10-03 12:03:23,577] org.mongodb.morphia.logging.MorphiaLoggerFactory: LoggerImplFactory set to org.mongodb.morphia.lo
gging.jdk.JDKLoggerFactory
←[33midentify-service_1  |←[0m WARN  [2016-10-03 12:03:24,346] org.mongodb.morphia.mapping.validation.MappingValidator: MisplacedProperty complained about com.p
rogether.services.id.representation.UserSession.expired : com.progether.services.id.representation.UserSession.expired is annotated as @Property but is a type t
hat cannot be mapped simply (type is java.time.OffsetDateTime).
←[33midentify-service_1  |←[0m WARN  [2016-10-03 12:03:24,347] org.mongodb.morphia.mapping.validation.MappingValidator: MisplacedProperty complained about com.p
rogether.services.id.representation.UserSession.lastAccess : com.progether.services.id.representation.UserSession.lastAccess is annotated as @Property but is a
type that cannot be mapped simply (type is java.time.OffsetDateTime).
←[33midentify-service_1  |←[0m WARN  [2016-10-03 12:03:24,348] org.mongodb.morphia.mapping.validation.MappingValidator: MisplacedProperty complained about com.p
rogether.services.id.representation.UserSession.started : com.progether.services.id.representation.UserSession.started is annotated as @Property but is a type t
hat cannot be mapped simply (type is java.time.OffsetDateTime).
←[33midentify-service_1  |←[0m WARN  [2016-10-03 12:03:24,365] org.mongodb.morphia.mapping.MappedField: Parameterized types are treated as untyped Objects. See
field 'properties' on class com.progether.services.id.representation.UserIdentity
←[33midentify-service_1  |←[0m INFO  [2016-10-03 12:03:24,476] org.mongodb.driver.cluster: Cluster created with settings {hosts=[mongo:27017], mode=SINGLE, requ
iredClusterType=UNKNOWN, serverSelectionTimeout='30000 ms', maxWaitQueueSize=500}
←[36mmongo_1             |←[0m 2016-10-03T12:03:24.529+0000 I NETWORK  [thread1] connection accepted from 172.19.0.3:59474 #1 (1 connection now open)
←[36mmongo_1             |←[0m 2016-10-03T12:03:24.597+0000 I ACCESS   [conn1]  authenticate db: progether-id { authenticate: 1, user: "peter", nonce: "xxx", ke
y: "xxx" }
←[36mmongo_1             |←[0m 2016-10-03T12:03:24.597+0000 I ACCESS   [conn1] Failed to authenticate peter@progether-id with mechanism MONGODB-CR: Authenticati
onFailed: UserNotFound: Could not find user peter@progether-id
←[33midentify-service_1  |←[0m INFO  [2016-10-03 12:03:24,598] org.mongodb.driver.cluster: No server chosen by PrimaryServerSelector from cluster description Cl
usterDescription{type=UNKNOWN, connectionMode=SINGLE, all=[ServerDescription{address=mongo:27017, type=UNKNOWN, state=CONNECTING}]}. Waiting for 30000 ms before
 timing out
←[36mmongo_1             |←[0m 2016-10-03T12:03:24.605+0000 I -        [conn1] end connection 172.19.0.3:59474 (1 connection now open)
←[33midentify-service_1  |←[0m INFO  [2016-10-03 12:03:24,616] org.mongodb.driver.cluster: Exception in monitor thread while connecting to server mongo:27017
←[33midentify-service_1  |←[0m ! com.mongodb.MongoCommandException: Command failed with error 18: 'auth failed' on server mongo:27017. The full response is { "o
k" : 0.0, "errmsg" : "auth failed", "code" : 18, "codeName" : "AuthenticationFailed" }
←[36mmongo_1             |←[0m 2016-10-03T12:03:25.128+0000 I NETWORK  [thread1] connection accepted from 172.19.0.3:59476 #2 (1 connection now open)
←[36mmongo_1             |←[0m 2016-10-03T12:03:25.133+0000 I ACCESS   [conn2]  authenticate db: progether-id { authenticate: 1, user: "peter", nonce: "xxx", ke
y: "xxx" }
←[36mmongo_1             |←[0m 2016-10-03T12:03:25.133+0000 I ACCESS   [conn2] Failed to authenticate peter@progether-id with mechanism MONGODB-CR: Authenticati
onFailed: UserNotFound: Could not find user peter@progether-id
```

`Dockerfile-mongo`:

```
FROM mongo:3.3
RUN su - mongodb -c "mongod" & sleep 5; mongo --eval "\
db.createUser({user: 'peter', pwd: 'password', roles: [{role:'readWrite',db:'progether-id'}]})" admin
RUN rm /tmp/mongodb-*.sock
CMD ["mongod", "--auth", "--smallfiles"]
```

`docker-compose.yml`:

```
version: '2'
services:
  identify-service:
    image: id-srv
    ports:
      - "8483:8483"
    links:
      - mongo
  mongo:
    image: my-mongo
    ports:
      - "27017:27017"
```

Answer (score 3):

I observe the following:

- When you run the compose file, the identify-service is complaining that the user is not created.
- There is nothing that ensures that the user creation is committed to the disk.
- MongoDB tends to work with data in RAM and it may be possible that it still didn't commit the data when it got killed by docker.

How to test:

- You should have the mongodb available after you launch the compose file. Connect to it and verify if the user is there.

How to solve:

- Add the user at runtime instead of at build time. Put the add user command in an entrypoint.sh and use that script as the entrypoint of your mongodb container.

Maybe adding a https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/command/fsync/ after the user creation would work too.